# Date iCal Date & Time Not Passed on Correctly

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I'm having an issue with the Date iCal module where the specific time is incorrect. The date is correct, the title and body are correct, but the time itself is incorrect.

It just defaults at noon and no matter what I seem to do, the time will not change.

At the moment you can find the calendar link here: http://www.egyptianstudysociety.com/events

And you can find the iCal feed link here: 
webcal://www.egyptianstudysociety.com/events.ics

I'd appreciate any help with this, because I'm absolutely lost.

Thanks! Matt

UPDATE------------------------

The current formatting is as follows: 02/14/2017 11:14:01:pm

And it does have an end date.

And here is the output for the .ics view:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Date iCal//NONSGML kigkonsult.se iCalcreator 2.20.2//
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT:Egyptian Study Society
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:calendar.110.field_date_time.0@www.egyptianstudysociety.com
DTSTAMP:20170214T180111Z
CREATED:20170123T175211Z
DESCRIPTION:Edouard Naville and Francis Llewellyn Griffith are often referr
 ed to as the first archaeologists to see the importance and grandeur of th
 e Great Temple at Bubastis and it is their descriptions and findings which
  continue to draw modern day archaeologists to the site of the once magnif
 icent temple and city.
DTSTART:20170222T190000Z
DTEND:20170222T200000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20170214T174303Z
SUMMARY:Naville\, Griffith & the Legacy of the Great Temple at Bubastis
URL;TYPE=URI:http://www.egyptianstudysociety.com/event/naville-griffith-leg
 acy-great-temple-bubastis
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

-----UPDATE

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Date iCal//NONSGML kigkonsult.se iCalcreator 2.20.2//
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME;VALUE=TEXT:Egyptian Study Society
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Denver
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20161106T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
TZNAME:MST
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20170312T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0600
TZNAME:MDT
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:calendar.110.field_date_time.0@www.egyptianstudysociety.com
DTSTAMP:20170214T182618Z
CREATED:20170123T175211Z
DESCRIPTION:Edouard Naville and Francis Llewellyn Griffith are often referr
 ed to as the first archaeologists to see the importance and grandeur of th
 e Great Temple at Bubastis and it is their descriptions and findings which
  continue to draw modern day archaeologists to the site of the once magnif
 icent temple and city.
DTSTART;TZID=America/Denver:20170222T120000
DTEND;TZID=America/Denver:20170222T130000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170214T174303Z
SUMMARY:Naville\, Griffith & the Legacy of the Great Temple at Bubastis
URL;TYPE=URI:http://www.egyptianstudysociety.com/event/naville-griffith-leg
 acy-great-temple-bubastis
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Check your date format.  Make sure the time value isn't messed up or set to 12:00 manually.

Comment: @iLLin I've updated my question with additional information. But I know it isn't set to 12:00 manually.

Comment: I think you need some type of offset (timezone).
`BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Phoenix
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19671029T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
TZNAME:MST
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE`

Comment: Also try changing it from 7pm or w/e it says to a different hour to verify.  See if the time tracks up or down.

Comment: I've updated my question with what I believe is the corrected added Timezone information, but it's still showing the noon time. I'll change the time and let you know.

Comment: Mine shows noon also, but if I change the time in the file, it changes to that time.  Also from looking at your event, it shows 12pm to 1pm for me on the website.  Are you sure that's not correct?